# R - How do you reference the boundaries of set objects?

Tags: r, set

I am working with interval objects in the `sets` package in `R` (documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/sets.pdf)).  These objects appear to be represented as lists, but I am having trouble manipulating their elements.  Here is an example of an interval and its structure and class.  The object created is of class `"interval"` and the structure shows that it is a type of list containing the boundary points of the interval, logical values for its closure at the boundaries, and an attribute signifying that it is an interval of real numbers.

```
#Create and print an interval
INTERVAL <- sets::interval(l = 3, r = 9, bounds = 'closed');
INTERVAL;
[3, 9]

#Show class
class(INTERVAL);
[1] "interval"

#Show structure
str(INTERVAL);
List of 1
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ l : num 3
  ..$ r : num 9
  ..$ lc: logi TRUE
  ..$ rc: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "domain")= chr "R"

#Extract boundary values
min(INTERVAL);
[1] 3

max(INTERVAL);
[1] 9
```

Presently I can extract the boundary values using the above commands, but I cannot re-assign them once they have already been created.  I have tried referencing the values from the list.  It is possible to use set operations from the `sets` package to take unions or intersections of sets, so I could do it this way, but I want to be able to directly alter the object without performing a set operation.

**My Question:** How do I reference a boundary value from the object `INTERVAL` above?  What is the simplest way to replace one of its boundaries with another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way, its way bit hackish but I hope this helps. I am not sure if you want to do assignment like this, you may need to elaborate a bit more. I may have misunderstood you completely. Please let me know.

Using unclass here to get each of the elements and assigning in the given object.
If you unclass it you can separately access each of the list component and then edit it.

```
INTERVAL <- sets::interval(l = 3, r = 9, bounds = 'closed');
intval <- unclass(INTERVAL)
intval[[1]]$l <- 0
class(intval) <- 'interval'
```

**Output:**

```
   # > print(intval)
   # [0, 9]
```